# Is the data actually decorreleted?

Tags: data-transformation, autocorrelation

I have a time series data where I have a variabel that shows me electricity price data week to week. The variabel has severe autocorrelation as it start in the high 90s for the first lag then slowly goes lower and lower. My question is, I have tried decorrelation/removing the autocorrelation and thought I had done it with a ARIMA model, but I then realized that what I was checking the autocorrelation on was the residuals and not the actual number I will have to use as that still showed quite a bit of autocorrelation. And even when I tried putting the lag to 52 so a year to year, it still showed severe autocorrelation. I have tried different types of transformation as Mahalanobis and Pre-whitening, but everything just gives the same. Where do I go wrong, or is it even possible to decorrelate data like this? Or hopefully, have I just mistunderstood things now and since my residuals now are decorrelated everything is good with the data?

Comment: Can you tell us why you're trying to decorrelate things? Oftentimes, the reason we decorrelate is to be able to make an iid assumption on the residuals of a model, such that we can "trust" p-values or confidence intervals that it provides. In this case, it's only the residuals that must be uncorrelated.

Comment: Okey thank you it was in the way you mentioned what I was trying to achieve and I just had a thought of "oh god, what if it's the other way around" but thank you again